# Laravel 5.5 change auth reset email template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm receiving email "http://localhost/administrator/password/reset?e41c382e270ec2aad6a14a6bcc934a68a2ee2e16382a54df1e33d71d5b01d12b" when I reset my password. However, in my route, I have the following code;

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
```

How can I rewrite the route so that it can take query params? Or alternatively, how can change the email of reset password so that it can show like :

http://localhost/administrator/password/reset/e41c382e270ec2aad6a14a6bcc934a68a2ee2e16382a54df1e33d71d5b01d12b , instead of query param(?).

Comment: I've done routes like `'password/reset/{token}'` for years and they've always come out the way you described: without query parameters.